# Jetpack Compose LazyVerticalGrid stuttering

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm migrating my app and for the grid view I used LazyVerticalGrid that loads images using coilPainter but the scrolling stutters a lot and it feels laggy. Does anyone have a solution or a better implementation for this?

```
    val photos: List<Photo>? by photosViewModel.photosLiveData.observeAsState(null)

    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                cells = GridCells.Fixed(3)
            ) {
                photos?.let { photosList ->
                    items(photosList) { photo ->
                        Image(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp).clickable {
                                photosViewModel.onPhotoClicked(photo)
                            },
                            painter = rememberCoilPainter(photo.url),
                            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.cd_details_photo),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                            alignment = Alignment.Center,
                        )

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**

Trying to move `rememberCoilPainter` above `Image` like `val painter = rememberCoilPainter(photo.url)` and use the `painter` inside the `Image` did not work

Comment: try to move `rememberCoilPainter` outside the `Image` call and save it in a variable (i.e `val image = rememberCoilPainter()`)

Comment: Still having the same behaviour

Comment: that's unfortunately pay for the compose. it's impossible to implement smooth 60fps scrolling even without images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating my compose image loading library to coil-compose I was forced to set a size to either the request builder or the image itself. The problem of the stuttering was caused by allowing the photo to load the original size and thus recomposing was done multiple times and loading the image had to wait for the picture to load. By setting e **fixed height** to the Image fixed the issue because the Images() were created and the recomposition was made only for the picture inside not for the Image itself with different height.

Comment: 我尝试了使用ImageRequest.Builder..size(imageSize),但是并没有明显的改善。滑动效果似乎并没有什么改善。

Answer (score 0):

`items` takes an additional parameter `key`, assign this parameter to a unique value like the index of each photo of your list, If you don't know how does that relate to scrolling jank? Or what the heck am I talking about? check out the following documentation for a detailed explanation:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle#add-info-smart-recomposition

Comment: for LazyColumn  - yes, for LazyVerticalGrid parameter `key` not present

Comment: `LazyGridScope.items` does contain a `key` param.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Glide, and based on the answer of gigi2peu I added a fixed size for the image like this:

```
GlideImage(
   modifier = Modifier
      .aspectRatio(1f)
      .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)),
   requestOptions = {
       RequestOptions()
            .override(200, 200)
            .encodeQuality(70)
   },
   imageModel = Uri.fromFile(File(image.path)),
   contentDescription = "Gallery Image"
)
```